# LDAP Querying via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ldap

I am attempting to write an LDAP query via VB.NET to pull back the atrribute of homeDirectory and throw in in a textbox.  The below code is used to query an LDAP user to check a group theyre a part of.  How can i turn the below in to pull back homeDirectory = textbox1.text.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim rootEntry As New DirectoryEntry("fake")
    Dim srch As New DirectorySearcher(rootEntry)

    srch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
    srch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=fake)(memberOf=CN=FAKE,OU=Citrix,OU=SecurityGroups,DC=fake,DC=fake))"
    Dim res As SearchResultCollection = srch.FindAll()

    If res Is Nothing OrElse res.Count <= 0 Then
        MsgBox("This user is *NOT* member of that group")
    Else
        MsgBox("This user is INDEED a member of that group")
    End If
End Sub
```

What it looks like now:

```
Dim rootEntry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://johndoe")
Dim srch As New DirectorySearcher(rootEntry)

srch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
srch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=)"
srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("homeDirectory")

Dim res As SearchResultCollection = srch.FindAll()
Dim homeDirectory As String = res(0).Properties("homeDirectory").ToString()
Dim user As SearchResult = res(0)

If user.Properties.Contains("homeDirectory") Then
    TextBox1.Text = user.Properties("homeDirectory").ToString()
End If

If res Is Nothing OrElse res.Count <= 0 Then
    MsgBox("This user is *NOT* member of that group")
Else
    MsgBox("This user is INDEED a member of that group")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell the `DirectorySearcher` which attributes you want to load (e.g.):

```
srch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("homeDirectory")
```

You can probably simplify the query now to just include the username for which you're looking:

```
srch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=fake))"
```

Then, assuming you have just one search result, you should be able to retrieve that property from the first result in your `SearchResultCollection`:

```
Dim user As SearchResult = res(0)
If user.Properties.Contains("homeDirectory") Then
    textbox1.Text = user.Properties("homeDirectory").ToString()
End If
```

Comment: how do i specify a user to search?

Comment: Are you not already doing that with the "fake" `samAccountName`? The result from your example should be the "fake" user.

Comment: it didnt bring back any results. let me post my code of how it looks now

Comment: If `srch.FindAll()` doesn't return anything then there's probably something wrong with your filter.

Comment: any idea what that is?  i updated the code im using now in my main post. it errors out w the filter is invalid

Comment: Something like `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=" & yourUserName & "))` *should* work. I'm not sure about the `Subtree` search scope option.

Comment: weird its giving me system.directoryservices.resuktpropertyvaluecollection